# ASPxGridView.GetChildDataRow is always null

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm dynamically binding my grid with a result of linq expression on PageLoad and at HtmlRowPrepared event i'm trying to reach a DataRow with

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.GetChildRowCount(visibleGrIndex); i++)
  {
    var row = grid.GetChildDataRow(visibleGrIndex, i); 
  }
```

but its ALWAYS NULL?

Answer (score 1):

[HtmlRowPrepared](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_HtmlRowPreparedtopic) is triggered once for every grid row. 
So, you can use this code to fetch data row:

```cs
private void Grid_HtmlRowPrepared(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.RowType == GridViewRowType.Group)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GetChildRowCount(e.VisibleIndex); i++)
        {
            var row = GetChildDataRow(e.VisibleIndex, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i dont want to reach specified row, i want to iterate over rows in any specified group row? DevX documentation says GetChildRowCount() returns count of child row at given group row and GetChildDataRow() returns DataRow in group row which specified zero-based index of that rows in that group. First method works well but second null always :(

Comment: I have updated my answer. Updated code works correctly in my app.

Comment: Still same problem continuing... in debug over assignment line, row is "The value of the local or argument 'row' is unobtainable at this time." and it acts as null when i put it to a nullcheck :(

Comment: You should post your grid markup or contact DevExpress support.

Comment: Gotcha! The problem is: I have nested groups!! There are group rows in groups and GetChildDataRow returns empty beacuse of child isn't a DataRow, is a GroupRow... Than you Mr.Filip, i gave you up :)